# How to delete old kernels without package management?

Tags: kernel, files

Is it a good idea to remove the `vmlinuz`, `system.map`, `initrd.img`, `config` and `abi` files from old kernels in `/boot` manually?

They're not listed in `dpkg`, because I installed Precise Pangolin without removing Lucid Lynx before.

Comment: Possible? Absolutely, simple `sudo rm` maneuver.  Is it a good idea?  This I think is what your question is.

Comment: I think that @adempewolff is right, but becarefull xD

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen for the faint of heart `/boot/$ sudo mv vmlinux ~/`, `~/$ sudo chown chris:chris vmlinux` and then finally `~/$ rm vmlinux` would also do the trick :P

Comment: @adempewolff well ok, I dont care if I screw up my os, just reinstall it, but I can understand that some people would as kthat, so I thought, maybe I should mention it

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I was being less than serious with my second comment.  It _is_ a good idea to always think twice about what you are doing when you use `sudo`, especially with a program like `rm`.

Comment: @adempewolff ;)

Answer (score 0):

Kernel version for Lucid Lynx is 2.6.32 and no other Ubuntu release uses that kernel. It is safe to remove those old Lucid's kernels runnning:

```
sudo rm /boot/*-2.6.32-*
```